# Fetching DeviceId through TelephonyManager in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, imei

```
public string GetIdentifier()
        {

            Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
            mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Forms.Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            return mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
        }
```

Trying to get DeviceId through above code but TELEPHONY_SERVICE is giving compile time error in Visual Studio(Xamarin +Android).How to correct this? 
Please see the image attached for reference.[ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OupHU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a little different in Xamarin Android

```
        Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
        return mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
```

Comment: Forms.Context is now obsolete. This code will raise a compiler warning.

Comment: Use Android.App.Application.Context instead